# What is 'superstition', and what does it affect?

Tags: trove

Among the list of character stats in Trove is one called **superstition**.  I've only ever found one item *a weapon* that augmented it in any way, and the tooltip is very mysterious.

[image: Superstition: Definitely might do something]

> Definitely might do something

What does superstition actually affect in Trove?

Comment: Superstition is "magic resistance". A lot of pets also contribute to it (samantha and cubesly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ongoing theories:** There is not a defined opinion about this attribute on the internet. The devs didn't came out with an official explanation about this stat, and even today people still debate this on chat. The following are explanations to the stat, based on internet communities:

From [Trove forums](http://forums.trovegame.com/showthread.php?1112-Superstition): It's a joke

> I'm 100% sure superstition increases your superstition.

From Trove Forums - [part 2](http://forums.trovegame.com/showthread.php?9763-Superstition): It's a joke

> It definitely might do something.

And of course there is some crazy conjectures like "the ability to drop more [pembocks](http://www.trovesaurus.com/item/mount/dog_corgi)".

From Trove [Wikia](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Player_Stats), they think it increases magic defense.

> Found on the Qubesly and Samantha pet (Allies) . Possibly increases magic resistance.

And on reddit, it's still a ongoing question. [Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Trove/comments/2h5zsu/does_anyone_know_what_superstition_does/) and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Trove/comments/2aav3i/superstition/).

**Real answer:** I know that answers need to be atemporal at StackExchange, but as an update to this, it seems that the [real effect](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Player_Stats) was found:  Allows you to see the ghosts of dead players during the Shadow's Eve event. Has no effect otherwise. Some players at the forums believe that is a [troll stat](http://forums.trovegame.com/showthread.php?116693-Superstition), some kind of garbage stat that never got removed from the game.

Answer (score 3):

It does exactly what it says: it just makes you superstitious about it. So far, it has no actual effect. It might have an effect later on in development, though, so it might change.

A close look at the possible values result in 7 (the most common lucky number,) 9 (a less common lucky number,) and 13 (the unluckiest number of all; given by, you guessed it, Sameowntha, the black cat.)

Even on the PTS server, where it's in official release, Superstition don't do anything good nor bad.

Things it doesn't do:

1. Influence rare item drop from box. That's referred to as Karma.
2. Cause Cloud Dungeons or Shadow Portals to spawn. Those would be made by procedural world generation.
3. Magic defense. There isn't even a physical defense!

Comment: Have you got any proof? Some people are speculating that it creates the chance for a portal to a [hidden dungeon to spawn in the Hub World](https://i.imgur.com/jsCLBI5.jpg), [far out into the Sea of Regret](https://i.imgur.com/qXBfag9.png).

Comment: It might be more of a developer in-joke.

Comment: Links. Check the links @Nefer007

Comment: Well then, I stand slightly corrected. Only the second link counted as proof. Now, as to why I think you are wrong, I'll tell you: a. That's the same model as a Shadow Portal. b. Hub worlds, like club, shadow, sky, tutorial, and adventure worlds, are built block-by-block using procedural world generation, meaning such a structure wouldn't just 'randomly' spawn. It would have been in the exact place for everyone in that hub world.

Answer (score 0):

No, superstition not is magic resistance, is thought to incrase the probability of drops, and magic find to incrase the forge level of the drops.

Answer (score 0):

The superstition stat is like jesus. Plenty of people have things to say he isnt real and people say he is but ultimately no one can provide evidence for either side. That being said, isn't this stat obviously just a joke made by the developers and furthered by trolls making stories about it that they in fact have no proof of? I noticed a lack of evidence consistently gets pointed out so what i'll do is debunk one of the only myths about this stat. https://www.reddit.com/r/Trove/comments/2h5zsu/does_anyone_know_what_superstition_does/

in this article someone says the stat helps you find more cloud islands above the sea of regret and drop rate. He doesn't have any evidence of this, he isn't credible on reddit, and it literally doesn't make sense that a stat would change how the Trove's engine renders chunks.
I would also like to debunk that it's a magic resistant stat. For one, there isnt an armor stat and for two, nothing deals magic damage.

Answer (score -1):

Well it does nothing, really. Maybe it wouldn't produce the placebo effect even If I didn't tell you, but the game is more fun if you believe it makes you better. When I first found out about this, it felt like a kick in the balls; like Santa Claus, you knew it doesn't exist but it was still fun to believe when you were a kid.

Comment: while you've put up an apparently good answer (having answered with a paragraph instead of a sentence), most of this appears to be commentary, and ultimately, your answer is simply "it does nothing". Can you provide a link to back up your findings?